# Are the contents of Iron Lockboxes pre-determined?

Tags: spiral-knights

In the game Spiral Knights, are the contents of Iron Lockboxes pre-determined?  Or is it determined when you open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that they are **determined when they are opened**, because if they would be predetermined, then the *Three Rings Design* Database would be **overloaded** with storing content for each and every one of the many unopened lockboxes out there. Instead, they just store a program which randomly selects an item from the *huge* list of available items, predominantly accessories.